# DRF updating data using AJAX call

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When I try to send data via the frontend to the serializer I get a HTTP 400 error. If I do it directly via the DRF browsable API it works though:

model:

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length = 128)
    date = models.DateField()

class Product(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField("serial", max_length = 31, unique = True)
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank = True, null = True)
```

serializer:

```
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields = ["id", "name",]
        
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shipment = ShipmentSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, request):
        product = Product.objects.get(serial = instance)
        product.shipment = Shipment.objects.get(id = request["shipment"]["id"])
        product.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["serial", "shipment",]    
        lookup_field = "serial"
        read_only_fields = ["serial",]
```

ViewSet:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_field = "serial"
    http_method_names = ["get", "patch", "put"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({url: `api/products/${serial}/`,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "PUT",
        data: {"shipment": shipment[0]},
        headers: {"X-CSRFTOKEN": csrf_token },
        success: function () {window.location = "?msg=ok";},
        error: function () {window.location = "?msg=error";}
});
```

Browser output:

```
PUT
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/d39f281f/
Status400
Bad Request
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred400 B (111 B size)
Referrer Policysame-origin
```

Request payload:

```
shipment=4
```

Response:

```
{"shipment":["This field is required."]}
```

or after some playing:

```
JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

why is the response `field is required` when there is a payload.

Comment: Likely because `shipment = ShipmentSerializer()` expects a shipment object, not a `pk`. Try to change it to `shipment = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Shipment.objects.all())` and see if it works

Comment: You're setting the request content-type to `application/json` but not sending JSON

Comment: JSON.stringify your data before send ajax call it will works

Comment: @bdbd I like this solution a lot, but the problem is I need my `GET` request from the API return `shipment: {"id": 1, "name": "...."}` and not just `shipment: 1`. Any idea if this can be done like you suggested?

Comment: That's a bit tricky. One way is to create a serializer for creating, and another for displaying. Or change the name of the key for displaying, for example `shipment_details` when displaying, and `shipment` when creating.

Comment: So one `read_only` with `id` and `name` and one `write_only` with just `id`? I tried that already but got stuck somewhere along the way.

Comment: Define two fields in your serializer: you can do `shipment_id` for writing and `shipment` for reading, or `shipment` for writing and `shipment_details` for reading

Comment: I've added an answer if you want to try it out

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem is to define two fields for `shipment`, one for writing and one for reading:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    shipment_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Shipment.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    shipment = ShipmentSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["serial", "shipment", "shipment_id"]
```

When you are updating, you can specify the id of the shipment using `shipment_id`:

```
{
    "shipment_id": 10,
}
```

When you are retrieving or listing, the shipment details will come under `shipment`:

```
{
    "serial": "",
    "shipment": {
        ... # shipment details
    }
}
```